# Computing the distance and weight matrix of a graph

Tags: matrix, graph, r

I would like to create an igraph object. First, I set up the size of igraph object — `n, m`, then create a random matrix. As a result matrix `B` will be filled. Matrix `B` is the adjacency matrix for the igraph object. Inside for-loops I compute the distance `d` (scalar) and the weight matrix `W`. I would like to improve the perfomance of calculation. I think it is possible because I have used 4 for-loops in my code:

```
n <- 6 
m <- 7 

mat <- matrix(sample(0:255, n*m, replace=T), nrow = n, ncol = m)
R <- 2

a <- 1 
b <- 1 

d <- 0 
e <- 0 
g <- 0 

W <- matrix(0, n, m) 
B <- matrix(0, n*m, n*m)

for (i in 1:n){
for (j in 1:m){
  for (i0 in 1:n){
  for (j0 in 1:m){
            d <- ((i0 - i)^2+(j0 - j)^2)^(1/2) 
            e <- ifelse(d <= R, 1, 0)
            g <- abs(mat[i,j] - mat[i0,j0])
            W[i0,j0] <- e * ((a*g)^2 + (b*d)^2)^(1/2)
  } # for i0
  } # for j0
  B[m * (i-1)+j,] <- c(t(W)) 

} #for_j
} #for_i
```

Could anyone please give me an idea how to rewrite the above code with fewer or no for-loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you would do it with no for loops. The `dist()` function computes the distance between every pair of rows of a matrix. So you have to apply it to two matrices:

1. the matrix `C` where each row contains the `i` and `j` coordinates of each vertex.
2. the matrix `matrix(M, ncol = 1)` where each row contains the value at a vertex.

---

```
M <- t(mat)
C <- cbind(c(row(M)), c(col(M)))
D <- as.matrix(dist(C, method = "euclidean"))
E <- as.numeric(D <= R)
G <- as.matrix(dist(matrix(M, ncol = 1), method = "manhattan"))
B <- E * ((a * G) ^ 2 + (b * D) ^ 2) ^ (1 / 2)
```

Note that in R, matrices are stored using "Column Major", i.e. column by column. So it would be more natural to pick that the second row/col in `B` corresponds to the item at row 2 and col 1 in `mat`. You chose the opposite (row 1 col 2) which forced me to start my code with `M <- t(mat)`. If you want to pick the more natural approach as I suggest, just replace that first line with `M <- mat`.

Comment: thanks you for review of code. I tried two option M<-mat and M<-t(mat), unfortunatly, I didn't see the difference. When I plot the igraph object I use: mylayout<-as.matrix(cbind(cx, -cy)), sing '-' before cy.

Comment: As the result I should obtain the symmetric matrix B. How can I do the calculation for upper right triangle (without the diagonal) only?

Comment: You can remove the two `as.matrix()` in my code, then the result will be of class `dist`. The code won't be noticeably faster. Maybe the only benefit is that `B` will occupy less memory space.